# After some commands, bash prints "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" for unknown reason

Tags: arch-linux, segmentation-fault

On my build of Arch Linux I've recently noticed a weird problem. After launching certain programs from the shell it will echo "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)".

Some examples of this are when I [close shutter, launch chrome, launch sublime text, or close emacs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCaM.png)

As far as I can tell the segfaults aren't affecting the programs, but they show up consistently and it's starting to get kind of annoying.

I have no idea what's causing them, and couldn't find any info on it after searching around for a while.

My shell is bash and my terminal is urxvt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common sources for this kind of problem (i.e. affecting multiple unrelated programs)

1. Faulty memory.  Use [memtester](http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/) or [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to test your memory.  Replace any bad DIMMs.   If your motherboard supports it, buy ECC RAM - it's usually only 10-30% more expensive.

Note that some distros (e.g. debian) are conveniently configured to add a grub entry to run `memtest86` when you install the `memtest86` package.  `memtester` can be run without having to reboot.

2. A bad library that's common to all affected programs.  Have you upgraded recently?  At a guess, I'd start looking suspiciously at gnome/gtk libraries as all programs you mentioned either rely on them or can be compiled to use them.
   other potential suspects include libc6.  You can use `ldd` to find out exactly which libs each program uses and compare them to find common libs.

Comment: I reinstalled gtk and noticed it segfaulted on install. That sent me searching through a chain of threads [ending here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode) Turns out I didn't have intel microcode updates enabled. Thanks!