# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is given back when launching most apps on archlinux after upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, glibc, segmentation-fault

Noob here !
I have archlabs which runs on archlinux. After normal upgrade, most apps do not run (texmaker, qt5ct ...), when running them from terminal they give the error : "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I examined most core dumps, couldn't figure out what is the problem, when I tried to run a backtrace, I found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240052/after-some-commands-bash-prints-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-for-unknown) to be describing this matter really well (second part of the answer), but does not provide steps for noobs to solve it.

here are 1st lines from the backtrace :

```
#0  0x00007ffff6a1405f in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff3d4063b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff3d4237b in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff3932c51 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff6dabe0f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff67bf422 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff6a1ebf3 in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff3d20800 (LWP 2433)):
#0  0x00007ffff69dd640 in __tzfile_compute () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff69dc57d in __tz_convert () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff69daa61 in ranged_convert () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff69dadac in __mktime_internal () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff6d9fd30 in qMkTime(tm*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff6e749ce in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff6e75068 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff6e7516d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007ffff6e75620 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007ffff6e7784c in QDateTime::setMSecsSinceEpoch(long long) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00007ffff6e79c81 in QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(long long, Qt::TimeSpec, int) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
```

after this, really long repetitive sections are listed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it did mention multiple solutions...
You can do it like this:

- First check if it's a software or hardware problem:

  - Boot from a live medium, play around with this: browse, start some programs, ...
     If this also fails you probably have bad memory and you need to change it. 
    To be certain you can also use [Memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/#downiso) to double check it.
- If everything works fine then you know it has something to with your installation. You now have multiple options:

  - Start by running by some small software that barely does anything and uses as few libs as possible, increase the 'size' of the software until it breaks down and come back to us. I would like this:

    - `/bin/true` (this a extremely small program that exits immediately with returncode 0)
    - `/bin/sleep 1000` (also small, it justs wait 1000 seconds and exits)
    - Continue with `cat somefile`, `less somefile`, `nano somefile`, `screen`, ...
    - If these all work start with graphical software: `xeyes`, `xterm`, ...
      By now we should have enough info to see what the problem is.
  - Also, run your software in [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). This might also provide more info to us.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed approach.
I have tested the memory using `sudo memtester 1024 5` in all loops all turned **ok**, I tried the suggested commands, all passed with no problem.
From among what also launches with no problem: LibreOffice, firefox, chromium, megasync, synapse, dropbox, syncthing, Rstudio, terminal (obviously). The problem is with particularly texworks, texmaker, texstudio (texlive works fine from terminal), qt5ct.
I suspected something related to qt5, because it was the last thing I updated before having this problem, downgrading did not solve the problem.

Comment: Based on that description (downgrading doesn't help): Create a backup of your system, remove the suspicious software completely (don't just downgrade it and make sure you also removed the configfiles) and reinstall it again. It's a quick, easy and clean solution.

Comment: Yep, I figured this kind of problems is not fixed easily.
Thanks a lot @Garo